# How to show multiple image in PDF from database using TCPDF?

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, tcpdf

I'm generating `PDF` using `TCPDF` but when get to display the multiple images from database in `PDF`, images not showing. When `print_r(html);exit;`, images path calling properly but not appearing.

```
<?php 
      $defect_photos =explode (',',$data['data']['defect_photo']);  
      $html = '<table border=1>';$link = base_url(); 
      foreach($defect_photos as $defect_photo){  
         $html .= "<tr><td><img src='$link/uploads/defects/$defect_photo'></td></tr>";
      }
      $html .= '</table>'; $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, ''); 
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you add a dot behind `$defect_photo`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'></td></tr>"'  I'm getting this error. @NicoHaase

Comment: I'm getting an image when `print_r($defect_photo)` the output but not showing in the pdf page.